# iPhone endlessly syncing

Tags: iphone, icloud, restore

Two weeks ago I had my iPhone battery replaced. Before bringing the iPhone to the Apple store I backed up everything on iCloud and reset the phone. After the repair I restored the device and everything works without problems.

The only strange thing is that my iPhone is syncing/restoring since the restore: when attached to Wi-Fi the sync icon is turning and when I leave a known Wi-Fi the phone asks to reactivate Wi-Fi to continue the restore.

Now

- everything seems to be restored (all the apps are there, all photos are there and so on)
- during two weeks it would have been possible to restore terabytes of data (my phone was on and on on Wi-Fi most of the time)

What is my phone doing? How can I stop the continuous sync?

**Update**

Looking at the comments and some research online I tried to

- disable (and reset) iCloud sync of 1Password
- disable Voice Memo syncronization

without effect.

When connected to the Mac iTunes shows:

> Syncing Apps to "Teo's iPhone" (Step 5 of 5)
>
> Waiting for items to copy

Comment: Did you reset your 1Password? https://learn2.agilebits.com/1Password4/iOS/Sync/iCloud/ios-icloud-not-working.html and this https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/24434/icloud-sync-not-working-properly

Comment: I tried with no effect. I also disabled the Sync of Voice Memos ... I'll update the question